# Typechecking throws error in VSCode in regular JS-File

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say i have a HTML element as following:

```
<progress value="1" max="10" id="site_progress"></progress>
```

VSCode shows a problem ('Property "max" does not exist on type "Element"'), if i select this element like this:

```
const progress = document.querySelector('#site_progress');
progress.max = 9;
```

There will be no problems, if i select via element selector:

```
const progress = document.querySelector('progress');
progress.max = 9;
```

Can i do something like type assertion to avoid this kind of behavior or what are good practises to handle this problem in regular javascript?

Comment: queryselector can return any type of element of you provide an id, or class etc.  So you will need to cast manually..

Comment: have you tried ```getElementById```

Comment: Typescript cannot check your HTML. It can only deduce that if the selector is `progress` then the result is `HTMLProgressElement | null`. This will work for every other element too. `div` => `HTMLDivElement`, `input` => `HTMLInputElement`, etc...
But if you add any other selector to it, it cannot do it.

Comment: What's a bit odd is, that even `input#id` doesn't tell TS, that the selected element is a `HTMLProgessElement` as far as i tested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I would just move to TS, but even then you would still need to cast.
To cast the type in JS you can do ->

```js
/** @type HTMLProgressElement */
const progress = document.querySelector('#id');
progress.max = 9;
```

In Typescript it would have been like ->

```js
const progress = document.querySelector('#id') as HTMLProgressElement;
progress.max = 9;
```

Another nice feature, you can create type guards, and this also helps the compiler.

eg, this below will work in both TS & JS.

```
const progress = document.querySelector('#id');
if (progress instanceof HTMLProgressElement)
    progress.max = 9;
```

One slight issue with the above, is if #id is not a Progress it will silently continue.  So another option is to throw an exception, this also acts as a type guard, but allows you to throw logical error messages when things are not right.

eg..

```
const progress = document.querySelector('#id');
if (!(progress instanceof HTMLProgressElement))
  throw new Error('#id not a progress');
progress.max = 9;
```

Comment: nice. Didn't know about this feature!